# 「最後に位置している指定文字列」以降の文字列を取得したい

Tags: php

やりたいこと
・最後の`</div>`以降の文字列を取得したい

対象文字列

```
取得しない<div>取得しない</div><div>取得しない</div>取得する
```

---

取得したい結果

```
取得する
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strrpos`で部分文字列の最後の出現位置を検索できます。

```
<?php

$search = "</div>";
$text = "取得しない<div>取得しない</div><div>取得しない</div>取得する";

$pos = strrpos($text, $search);
if ($pos !== false) {
    echo substr($text, $pos + strlen($search));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/.*<\/div>/', '', '取得しない<div>取得しない</div><div>取得しない</div>取得する')
```